# Where do I place the launch image "Default.png" in my iPhone app's project directory?

Tags: iphone, xcode

In the Apple documentation, it says...

> iPhone OS looks for a Default.png
>   file, located in the top level of the
>   application bundle.

but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to get the image in that location in the bundle (I'm new to all this).  I'm assuming my image will end up in the right place in the bundle when I compile it so long as I add it to the project correctly and place it in the right location in the project directory.  My questions are...

1. Where in my project directory should I place the "Default.png" image?
2. Do I need add it to the project through Xcode?  If so, how?

Thanks so much in advance for all your help!  I'm going to continue researching this question right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add it to the Resources group in Xcode. It will end up in the root of the app bundle.